Specifying non-PyPI dependency
I have written a package first_package with Poetry and installed it to /usr/local, which is on sys.path, so first_package can be imported like any other package installed via the operating system (AlmaLinux 8 in this case).
I have now written another package second_package which depends on first_package.  However I am not sure how to define the dependency in pyproj.toml.  If I just specify:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
first_package = "^1.6.0"

when I run poetry lock I get the error
SolverProblemError

Because second-package depends on first-package (^1.6.0) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Should this this work or does the resolving rely on all the packages being on PyPI?  If it should work, what is the correct syntax to define the dependency in pyproj.toml?
Note that this is not a duplicate the problem of referring to a module in a script, where both are part of the same package.  In the case here, I have two separate packages.
Note that is also not a duplicate of the problem of using a relative path to the first package as the path is not necessarily the same in the development environment as that in the installation environment. A solution could be to try to ensure that these two are the same, but here there is the problem that Poetry by default generates a my_package/my_package directory structure, which adds an extra directory level which will not be present under /usr/local/lib/python3.xx/site-packages.

From https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/: By default, Poetry is configured to use the PyPI repository […]. So, when you add dependencies to your project, Poetry will assume they are available on PyPI. From https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies: To depend on a library located in a local directory or file, you can use the path property
